# What is the opposite of hermaphrodite? I.e., having no sex organs?

Tags: single-word-requests

How could one describe an animal that is neither male nor female, because it has no sex organs?

But it could choose which sex organs to develop based on the environmental needs.

Not hermaphroditic because that means having both sets of sex organs, and not androgynous because (I believe) that describes solely appearance.

> The _______ toad is...

Comment: *Eunuch* (male only).

Comment: Can you clarify the context? What exactly is your character (a human with a medical condition, an animated doll, an alien blob creature, etc)? What type of word are you looking for (medical, slang, etc)?

Comment: What do you mean by "no sex organs"?

Comment: Question amended. I remember asking bc I remembered some animals had this, and also a character from an anime. They were sexless but would "choose" their sex.

Comment: *Sex organs de novo on demand?*  Is the potential for an animal to develop such a sex organ in some sense a sex organ or at least a *proto* sex organ? I've never run across an example of an animal that could develop sex organs *from scratch* based on environmental considerations.

Comment: OED: **asexual, adj. and n. A. adj. 1. Biology. Lacking sexual organs or function;  Also of reproduction: occurring without the fusion of male and female gametes, e.g. by fission, budding, or parthenogenesis;**. *1995 The life cycle is complex and includes many stages. The most common asexual form found in stool and water samples is the oocyst* =.2005   *What the aspens really illustrate is the power of asexual (or vegetative) reproduction.* **B. n. 1. Biology. An organism which does not reproduce sexually; an asexual,** *1927 Medium sized and small worms become apparently normal asexuals.*

Comment: "No sex organs" means not an animal such as a toad. Toads **can switch sexes**. So easy to **look up**.

Comment: As context and a sentence are lacking, this BBC article on parthenogenesis  might be of help: http://www.bbc.co.uk/earth/story/20151216-virgin-births-are-happening-everywhere

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That depends on the exact meaning(s) that you want to convey. You might use "**asexual or non-sexual**" or something similar like "**neuter or neutral**". Specifically, as far as "***having no sex organs***" goes, I think "**neuter or neutered**" comes closest to your meaning.

> The *"**neuter**"* character is...

https://www.thefreedictionary.com/asexual

https://www.thefreedictionary.com/neuter

I also found "**genderless**" and a number of other interesting possibilities here:

https://nonbinary.miraheze.org/wiki/Agender

Comment: This isn’t a particularly clear choice. I have never heard “asexual” used to refer to a lack of sexual organs when it refers to a human... or humanoid (which I assume the op’s character is). I have mostly heard it used to refer to the [asexual sexuality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asexuality), or some other similar meaning like not having sex. I think that “non-sexual” has the same problem.

Comment: @Laurel. Thanks, but I have to disagree with you. In biology there are some primitive organisms that are "asexual" in that way and one of the definitions of "asexual" fits the question. I agree that it is less common than the typical usages. I also consider "character" in the example to be not a particularly clear choice of nouns.

Comment: @DS - Please see the first adjective definition for "asexual" at the TFD link that I provided. I understood that definition completely. I think you may be mis-applying the social definition for "asexuality" to the biological definition of "asexual".

Comment: The problem you're encountering is twofold. First, you should provide the definition of the sense you're thinking of in the answer itself. Rather than simply providing a link, give a quotation that shows the meaning you're thinking of. For instance, Merriam-Webster's definition of its first sense of [*asexual*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/asexual) is: "lacking sex or functional sex organs // *asexual* plants." Second, the question itself is unclear (Is it a person who *never* had sex organs, or somebody who's had them removed?), so an answer here could be premature.

Comment: I thought the answer was a helpful one, if not complete by some standards. Perhaps a better answer will be offered by someone.

Comment: The author Bruce Sterling had a character like this  in a story once, and he referred to them as a 'neuter'.

Comment: Thanks @Rattler. I'm glad that fit in here. Apparently different literary types need to be taken into account as well. I have a science background and, not knowing the nature of the actual "character" in the example, I offered my answer, I thought the end link was a helpful one for "added" possibilities - at wiki/Agender (for more options). Wow...I actually ask questions on SE to get helpful answers... Anyone else?

Comment: When I get half a moment, I will  look up the usage and provide the actual quote so that you can include it in your answer.

Comment: I like the adjective 'neuter'. @user22542 your answer is good but not very structured, I find it hard to read...

Comment: Toads are not neuter.  And for a man, neutered is one thing (general meaning: no testicles) I have never heard of a female being "neutered". For my money, this answer is completely off. Sorry.